# Typescript & React Component that accepts onChange for both TextArea and Input

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript and I am trying to create an input component that, if it receives `type="text"` it renders an `input` and if it receives `type="textarea"` it renders, you got it, a `textarea`. The problem is that typescript is complaining when I use the component on my code together with a `onChange`, it seems it wont allow me to use two types on the same event?

It shows me:

```
Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e?: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'e' are incompatible.
Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
```

input.js

```
interface InputProps {
  className?: string;
  type?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange?: (e?: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
}

const Input: FunctionComponent<InputProps> = ({ type = 'text', ...props }) => {
  if (type === 'textarea') {
    return <textarea {...props} />;
  }
  return <input type={type} {...props} />;
};
```

usage:

```
class Usage extends React.Component<State> {
  state: State;

  onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <Input placeholder="Write an something..." onChange={this.onInputChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

---

**UPDATE**

The way I solved it for the moment is by saying that event can be of type `any`, but that's kind of a hack

```
type CommonProps = {
  className?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  type?: string;
  onChange?: (e: any) => void;
};
```

Comment: Could you paste your typescript version and @types/react version? It seems to work for me but probably doing sth differently. BTW it actually complains about this `undefined` part so that e is optional.

Comment: @barnski typescript - v3.2.1 / @types/react - v16.7.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a discriminated union to pass in two types of arguments, one for `text` and the other for `textarea`. This has the added bonus of ensuring the handler and the type are in sync.

```
type InputProps = { // The common Part
    className?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
} & ({ // The discriminated union
    type?: "text";
    onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
} | {
    type: "textarea";
    onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
})

const Input: FunctionComponent<InputProps> = (props: InputProps) => {
    if (props.type === 'textarea') {
        return <textarea {...props} />;
    }
    return <input {...props} />;
};


class Usage extends React.Component<State> {
    state: State;

    onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Input placeholder="Write an something..." onChange={this.onInputChange} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Was too long, had to add as answer

Comment: Works for me: https://github.com/dragomirtitian/so-answers/tree/so-53943737

Comment: It worked with a few adjustments. It will fail whenever I try to destructure props. Thanks!

Comment: @JCQuintas yeah distructuring will not work as expected because of the union.. that is why I removed it. (Delete the answer with the error, it will get downvoted otherwise, with good cause)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a class incase you are using typescript.
The normal function does not allows the `|` in the typescript prop types.

This should be your `Input.js` file:

```
export interface IInputProps {
  className?: string;
  type?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange?: (e?: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
}

export class Input extends React.Component<IInputProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: IInputProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { props, props: { type } } = this;
    if (type === 'textarea') {
      return <textarea {...props} />;
    }
    return <input type={type} {...props} />;
  }
}
```

and here is how it can be used:

```
class Usage extends React.Component<State> {
  state: State;

  onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Input placeholder="Write an something..." onChange={this.onInputChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it will evaluate if it is a `Input` or a `TextArea`:

[image]

Comment: Hm .. what is your definition of `IInputProps` ? The code you provide has the same error in `Usage`

Comment: TypeScript V3.2.2

Comment: your code works with `strict:false`, but OP's code would have worked with strict off as well... I'm guessing `strictFunctionTypes`is what is causing the error on the assignment of `onChange`