# Using typescript generics in Reactjs function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the next component in my react application:

```
import "./styles.css";

type InpuType = "input" | "textarea";

interface IContainer {
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  as: InpuType;
}

const Container = ({
  name,
  placeholder,
  as,
  ...rest
}: IContainer &
  (
    | React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>
    | React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
  )) => {
  const Comp = as || "input";
  return <Comp name={name} placeholder={placeholder} {...rest} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container name="hi" as="textarea" placeholder="start" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `...rest` are all the default props that could be added for a `textarea` or `input`.
 I have a typescript issue here `<Comp name={name} ...`, hovering over the component i get this message:

```
Type '{ autoComplete?: string | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; cols?: number | undefined; dirName?: string | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; form?: string | undefined; ... 261 more ...; placeholder: string; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ClassAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & ClassAttributes<...> & TextareaHTMLAttributes<...>'.
```

and i am not sure how to get rid of that. 
 Question: Why the issue appear and how to solve it? 
 demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-z6dk4i?file=/src/App.tsx:379-396

Comment: This is because the two types (input and textarea) have different properties. I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943737/typescript-react-component-that-accepts-onchange-for-both-textarea-and-input

Comment: @Arnau, there is no way to work with `<Comp ` , i should render conditionally `input` or `textarea`?

Comment: @Arnau, could you help?

Comment: @Arnau, also , i tried the solution but it does not work.

Comment: I think that you should just go with separate components for Input and Textarea. Generics are okey but you can end up with readability issues... and as you can see - typings issues.

Comment: @kinduser, is there a way to use my approach without separating the components?\

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing all the native props using rest (`{...rest}`) maybe it would be better to just differentiate the props between `textarea` and `input`.

```
interface IContainer {
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  textareaProps?: React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>;
  inputProps?: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
}

const Container = ({
  name,
  placeholder,
  textareaProps,
  inputProps,
}: IContainer) => {
  if (inputProps) {
    return <input {...inputProps} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} />;
  }

  return <textarea {...textareaProps} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} />;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-j9kgh2?file=/src/App.tsx:51-523

Comment: there is not possible to use my approach? It will really help me,.

Comment: @Asking There have to be some _type guard_, some condition to check what component you want to render, because there are different props for each of components.

Comment: how it should look? Could you help please? I tried to Omit some props but this is not useful

Answer (score 0):

you should create a function and create the inputs based on what you pass to it

```
import "./styles.css";

type InpuType = "input" | "textarea";
interface IComp {
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  as: InpuType;
  rest?: any;
}
const Comp = ({ as, name, placeholder, ...rest }: IComp) => {
  switch (as) {
    case "input":
      return <input name={name} placeholder={placeholder} {...rest} />;
    case "textarea":
      return <textarea name={name} placeholder={placeholder} {...rest} />;
  }
};
interface IContainer {
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  as: InpuType;
}

const Container = ({
  name,
  placeholder,
  as,
  ...rest
}: IContainer &
  (
    | React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>
    | React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
  )) => {
  return <Comp as={as} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} {...rest} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container name="hi" as="textarea" placeholder="start" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use my approach wihout separating the components?

Comment: I have no idea about your solution, you defined Comp as a constant but treated it as a component